# What does it mean when my answer is deleted by a moderator "Via Vote"?

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-answers

My answer was deleted by a Mod, but the comment on the deletion says "via Vote":

[image]

What does this mean? It looks like it was deleted by a moderator, not by collecting delete votes from community users, so why does it say "via Vote"?

Comment: This issue came up recently and I thought I'd convert my comment into a Q&A in case other people have this question in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What does 'via Vote' mean in the timeline of a deleted post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352753/what-does-via-vote-mean-in-the-timeline-of-a-deleted-post)

This meta question explains what "Via Vote" means here. This message is an automated comment that tells you that the question accumulated enough votes to be deleted. It may come up if the answer gets 3 delete votes from users, but it also comes up when a mod deletes a question since they do so by voting to delete with their binding "super vote".

That comment isn't written by the moderator and it doesn't mean anything about the community or any real sort of voting: it's just a confusing consequence of the way the system handles moderator deletion.